# shopware6, When the product price edited at the orders at admin and saved, after saving the orderState changes to open by default, how to change it?

Tags: shopware

When the product price edited at the orders at admin and saved, after saving the order state changes to open by default even if it is in progress state before, from where can I check it and make it customized.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think this is intended, if you change a price of an order, it must be reprocessed. This is why Shopware 6 sets resets the order status when changing prices of an existing order.

When setting a breakpoint in `\Shopware\Core\System\StateMachine\StateMachineRegistry::transition` during saving the order, it is not hit -> so this does not run through the state machine.

The order is recreated in `\Shopware\Core\Checkout\Cart\Order\RecalculationService::recalculateOrder` so you can try to hook into

```
\Shopware\Core\Checkout\Cart\Order\CartConvertedEvent
```

and overwrite the initial state.

Problem would be to distinguish new orders and recalculated ones. I suggest you look at the order state history and set the state you need in case the order was having a previous state of `processing`.

Comment: yes but for my plugin for custom state(ask for quote) i need to stick to same state only so that admin manually change the state to ( quote offer). for other edits(address, payment, shipping) its stick to same state except the product item and price. I need to have same behaviour as in address edit.

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: I need to write in backend controller? do we need to register backend controller also at srvice.xml?

Comment: The approach was to use a Observer to listen to the above event .... but I am not sure if that works, you have to try.